# SGE scheduler- how to print requested resource of an ended job?

Tags: cluster-computing, pbs, qsub, sungridengine

I just forget how much memory I requested for a job which has ended. It seems to me that the memory I requested is not enough. 
I requested the memory by `qsub -l h_vmem=?G`. 
Is there any way I can find it (SGE scheduler)? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a epilogue script for this. Example script `epilogue.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "#########################"
echo "Begin PBS Epilogue" `date`
echo "Epilogue Args:"
echo "Job ID: $1"
echo "User ID: $2"
echo "Group ID: $3"
echo "Job Name: $4"
echo "Session ID: $5"
echo "Resource List: $6"
echo "Resources Used: $7"
echo "Queue Name: $8"
echo "Account String: $9"
echo "End PBS Epilogue" `date`
echo "#########################"
exit 0
```

Example submit script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N test1
#PBS -o logs/
#PBS -e logs/
#PBS -l walltime=00:00:59
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -l mem=6G
#PBS -l vmem=6G
#PBS -l epilogue=/path/to/epilogue.sh

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

mkdir -p logs/

<some code to run here>
```

Note the line:

```
#PBS -l epilogue=/path/to/epilogue.sh
```

This tell the job to run `epilogue.sh` when the job completes. The output of `epilogue.sh` will appear in the standard output log file.